# Lint output not including line numbers and file

Tags: layout, visual-studio-2015, build, xamarin.android, lint

I get following output from lint during my application's build

```
 This TableRow layout or its TableLayout parent is useless [UselessParent]
 This TableRow layout or its TableLayout parent is useless [UselessParent]
 This TableLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is useless [UselessParent]
 This RelativeLayout layout or its LinearLayout parent is useless; transfer the background attribute to the other view [UselessParent]
```

How can I make it navigate me to the respective file by double clicking it, like in **Error List**? Or at least show me the file with line number?

Comment: Are you using lint command?

Comment: I use <AndroidLintEnabled>true</AndroidLintEnabled> in csproj file.